# jQuery's .map() returns array, not a matched set (jQuery object)

Tags: jquery

When using the .map() method, I'm getting back an array with two nodes I think (not an jQuery object/matched set). I want to apply a class this set but nothing happens.

```
$('input#substance, input[name="atc_code"]').map(function() {return $(this).prevAll('label:first')});
```

Returns:

```
[x.fn.x.init[1], x.fn.x.init[1]]

[
x.fn.x.init[1]
0: label
context: input#substance.ui-autocomplete-input
length: 1
prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]
__proto__: Object[0]
, 
x.fn.x.init[1]
0: label
context: input.small ui-autocomplete-input
length: 1
prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]
__proto__: Object[0]
```

It selects correctly but why can't I use this array? Why is it not a jQuery object?

The HTML:

```
<div class="fieldset-container">
   <label>Substance</label>
   <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span> 
   <input type="text" name="substance" id="substance" maxlength="22" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus="autofocus" class="ui-autocomplete-input">

   <label title="Required field">ATC code<span class="ma">*</span></label>
   <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><input type="text" class="small ui-autocomplete-input" name="atc_code" maxlength="7" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">

   <label>Year</label>
   <div class="small">
      <select name="year">...</select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It selects correctly but why can't I use this array? Why is it not a jQuery object?

It is, but this is one of those confusing times when the elements *within* the jQuery object are, themselves, jQuery objects. 99.999% of the time, a jQuery set contains DOM elements, but it's *possible* to have jQuery sets containing other things. In particular, when you use `.map`, the resulting jQuery object contains whatever your mapping function returns, unchanged. In your case, you were returning jQuery objects from your mapping function, and so that's what was in your resulting jQuery set. (And if that isn't confusing enough, jQuery also has **two** different `map` methods: The [one that's specific to instances](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and that returns a jQuery object, which is the one you used, and one that's [not specific to an instance](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and returns an array.)

You can solve this by having your mapping function return raw DOM elements:

```
$('input#substance, input[name="atc_code"]').map(function() {return $(this).prevAll('label:first')[0]});
// The new bit -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/UVEYEYE/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/UVEYEYE/1/edit)

Alternately, you can do this without `.map`:

```
$('input#substance').prevAll('label').first().add(
  $('input[name="atc_code"]').prevAll('label').first()
);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/UVEYEYE/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/UVEYEYE/2/edit)

Comment: I've already tried this, it won't work. These two elements are siblings and `prevAll('label:first')` will only return *one* element, whereas I need two. This is why I have to resort to `.map()`.

Comment: Not at all, TJ Crowder. According to my console I can see that it selects the two (different) elements that I want. But it puts them into an array =(

Comment: @silkfire: LOL And meanwhile I added an example showing that my change to your code worked.

Comment: Much better now. Solved it with `prevAll('label:first').get()` inside the mapping closure

Comment: @silkfire: Note that when you use `get` with zero or a positive number, it's equivalent to using `[]`, but with the overhead of a function call. So `prevAll('label:first')[0]` is more efficient. (`get` only really makes sense if you use negative indexes, which are offsets from the end of the set.)